# Unable to Login Using AuthLogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm trying to use authlogic, but apparently I'm doing something wrong. After creating users successfully (verified with User.all in console), I would try to log in but only to fail. What am I doing wrong?

Also, RubyMine marked
    UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
as erroneous because UserSession.new has no parameters
Is that just a problem with RubyMine?

Here's my model code

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |config|
    config.login_field = :email
  end

  validate :cannot_exceed_100_users

  protected
  def cannot_exceed_100_users
    if User.count > 100
      errors.add_to_base('Cannot have more than 100 users.')
    end
  end
end


class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  def to_key
    [session_key]
  end
end
```

---

Here's my controller code

---

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      logger.info 'success'
      redirect_to games_path
    else
      logger.info 'failed'
      render :action=>'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

---

Here's my login page code

---

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag :action=>'create' do %>
    <p>Please Log In</p>

    <div>
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to 'register', new_user_path %>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I think you're creating your session incorrectly. I'm no Authlogic guru but I think you're [supposed to do it like this](http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/file/README.rdoc):

```
session = UserSession.new(:login => params[:email], :password => params[:password])
session.save
```

Or, you could use [`create`](http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/Session/Existence/ClassMethods#create-instance_method):

```
session = UserSession.create(:login => params[:email], :password => params[:password])
```

All the Authlogic constructors appear to take named arguments in a Hash (using the usual Ruby auto-hashification), that's probably why RubyMine is complaining about your `UserSession.new` call having incorrect arguments.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply; I thought params[:user_session] would be the same as listing things out explicitly. Let me try it first.

Comment: RubyMine is actually saying the constructor takes zero arguments. I think I'll just going to ignore that part.

Comment: @Max: Is `@user_session.save` failing or are you failing to retrieve the session on the next request?

Comment: @user_session.save is failing

Comment: @Max: You should be able to use `UserSession.new(params[:user_session])` if your form used `:login` instead of `:email`. And have you compared what you're doing against the [example application](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example)?

Comment: Also, the documentation had @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session]) as an example; so I don't think that was the problem...

Comment: I've tried both :email and :login, but I used form_tag instead of form_for. Changing that now.

Comment: @Max: But your form uses `:email` where Auhtlogic expects `:login` and you're using [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) not [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) and [`f.text_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field) so `params[:user_session]` won't contain anything.

Comment: @Max: You could also try adding `:remember_me => true` to your `UserSession.new` call.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But it still doesn't work. Changing form_tag to form_for alone didn't fix it; while using f.text_field :login gave an undefined method exception: undefined method `login' for #<UserSession: no credentials provided>

Comment: @Max: Sorry, didn't see the config change in your user model. Does `f.text_field :email` do anything useful?